# Using require with root path variable in VSCode

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, require

I am using global variable `__root` with path of my root app directory then I am using require to load code from other files.

```
const Parser = require(__root + '/parsers/Parser')
```

The issue is that vscode does not understand what is happening:

1. Intellisense does not work
2. Object type is shown as any (if path is correct vscode grabs right type)

What are the options to solve this? Can you share your practices to resolve this issue?

Comment: Maybe with [using webpack aliases](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig#_using-webpack-aliases) you can get rid of the `__root` variable.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @HaaLeo. I didn't knew that webpack can be used with back-end projects. Solution looks good, but I have never prepared webpack before (only used with frameworks which has everything prepared), so I am little bit worried that it would take much time.

Comment: This should not take you long. You just need to create a `jsconfig.json` in your projects root directory and set the `compilerOptions.paths` attribute as described in the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VS Code's intellisense cannot understand dynamic import paths like `root + '/path'`. There are no workarounds for this, nor are the plans to address this in the immediate future.

However, with static require import paths, you can configure how VS Code resolves the imports by configuring a [`jsconfig.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_javascript-projects-jsconfigjson). The two options you probably want are [`baseUrl` and `paths`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html)

Setting up a `jsconfig.json` will not change the runtime behavior of your code, only how VS Code IntelliSense handles your project. You can use a `jsconfig.json` along with webpack aliases

Comment: Thank you. This could be used as alternative.

Comment: Would have been nice if the example  was in the answer  of modified `jsconfig.json`. So, for example, how we could force it to resolve `baseUrl` or `root` in the `include`